# Can @load trigger after the component was unmounted?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, gsap

Hi I'm working on a vue 3 app and I'm seeing a weird behaviour I don't understand.
My general question is: **can @load trigger after the component was unmounted?**
And if yes, what can be done about it to stop it completely?

---

Context

**Here's an image with a @load**

```
<img class="the-image" :id="imageId" :src="imgSrc" @load="handleAfterLoad()">
```

**I then have a method handleAfterLoad**

> ```
> handleAfterLoad() {
>   this.$nextTick(() => {
>     gsap.to(`#${this.imageId}`, {
>       scale: 1,
>       opacity: 1,
>       delay: 0.2,
>       duration: 0.5,
>       onComplete: function () {
>         this.handleAfterDisplay()
>       }.bind(this),
>     });
>   });
> },
> ```

Globally it works well.
But it behaves as if when the component is unmounted, the @load is trigerring handleAfterLoad afterwards anyway as I'm getting an error: *GSAP target #imageId_idiwja2phz2* not found. Same with a simple console.log(), the console.log() appears after the component was unmounted.

It only happens with Low connection throttling with devtools

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unknown if there are conditions under which the component or element could be unmounted, and whether it's possible for imageId to change value. It's messy to rely on selectors when you can deal with components, use template refs for gsap.to() call, all proper libs support this. Avoid the case when this could happen when the comp is unmounted by using a condition inside handleAfterLoad

Comment: Thank you for your reply and recommendations. The setup is a bit dense so I didn't want to overcharge the topic with code. The question is more general, as in: does @load stop/cancel on unmount? or does it need to be stopped manually? If it always stops on its own on unmount, then my problem is someplace else and I'll investigate someplace else (such as the unmount itself and its conditions).

Comment: Event listeners that are set in comp templates are handled by the framework and so automatically removed on unmount, chances are low that handleAfterLoad could be triggered after unmount. Function execution can't be stopped in JS from the outside, that's why you need if(this.isCompUnmounted) at least inside nextTick (not sure if it's necessary) and probably handleAfterDisplay. MCVE stands for "minimal", if the problem persists, make sure you isolated it from irrelevant code before posting

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, @ load will be triggered after uninstalling the component. If you want it not to be triggered, some alternative methods are needed,

```
data(){
  isDestroy: false,
},
destroy() {
  this.isDestroy = true
},
methods:{
  handleAfterLoad() {
    if (this.isDestroy) return

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      gsap.to(`#${this.imageId}`, {
        scale: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        delay: 0.2,
        duration: 0.5,
        onComplete: function () {
          this.handleAfterDisplay()
        }.bind(this),
      });
    });
  },
}
```